# Modifying rmdformats::robobook to display pages by header level

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using `rmdformats::robobook` as my format for an r-markdown document. While I like the depth of the TOC for that template, I dislike the continuous scrolling. I prefer how `rmdformats::material` only allows you to scroll as far as the 1st level header / starts a new page for each h1 (but I dislike that I can't increase the depth of the TOC).

So, my question: Is there a simple way to modify or an argument in the yaml that would tell it to make a new page by some level of header (e.g. just h1 or h1 and h2, but not h3)? I guess similar to how the TOC and page display in [R Markdown: the Definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/) function (I could not find that available as a template).

Reproducible code:

```
---
title: "tmp"
output: 
  rmdformats::robobook:
    toc_depth: 2
    toc_float: 
      collapsed: FALSE
    use_bookdown: TRUE
---

# Section 1
`r OpenRepGrid::randomWords(250)`

## Subsection 1 
`r OpenRepGrid::randomWords(250)`

### not in TOC
`r OpenRepGrid::randomWords(250)`


# Section 2
`r OpenRepGrid::randomWords(250)`

## Subsection 2
`r OpenRepGrid::randomWords(250)`

### not in TOC
`r OpenRepGrid::randomWords(250)`
```